# query an sql code, which is not presented the data it should be

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i'm alittle confused.
When i'm sending a query of ORDER BY `paramater` desc it should load and present the rows order by the highest number of that paramater to the lower one.

This is my code that im running:

```
<?php
        $p = 1;
        $loadusers = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY `gpower` DESC");
        $z = 0;
        while ($me = mysqli_fetch_array($loadusers)) {
            $z++;
            if (($z % 20) == 0) {
                $p += 1;
            }
            if ($me['id'] == $userinfo['id']) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isset($_GET['sp'])) {
            $p = intval($_GET['sp']);
        }
        $sl = (($p * 20) - 20);
        $el = $p * 20;
        $loadrank = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY `gpower` DESC LIMIT $sl,$el");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($loadrank) < 1) {
            $p = 1;
            $sl = (($p * 20) - 20);
            $el = $p * 20;
            $loadrank = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY `gpower` DESC LIMIT $sl,$el");
        }
        $i = $sl;
        while ($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($loadrank)) {
            $i++;
            ?>
            <tr <?php echo ($rs['id'] == $userinfo['id']) ? "style='background: #7d2222';" : ""?>>
                <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo secure($rs['name']); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo secure($rs['troops']); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo clanName($con, $rs['name']); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $rs['gpower']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    ?>
```

and this is what i'm getting :
[image: Daniel should be the first one that ranked but for some reason he is the 7 one.]

Any ideas why does it happend guys?

Comment: What's the type of `gpower` field? `Varchar`?

Comment: @u_mulder gpower type is Binary(64)

Answer (score 0):

Your getting a descending ALPHA order

Convert gpower to an int  (In SQL Server)

```
...Order by cast(gpower as int) Desc
```

Comment: I can't do that. i need to store a big numbers, more than 2 billons.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem was i've used a Binary type for the `gpower` cloumn.
i've changed it to float and it worked.
When you're using a "ORDER BY `paramater` DESC" it will only work if the paramater is numeric type.

Comment: Actually, your could also sort by padded strings asc or desc.  As long as the string length is sufficient to cover the max length.  Take a peek at LPAD().  For example, a value of 25 padded could be '000025'